# SSIS flat file source not importing all records in some conditions

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a newbie working on SSIS Packages, Flat file is the source and SQL DB is the destination. source file has approx 8000 records and it works completely fine, but sometimes when there is a huge single record approx 6000 kb, SSIS skips all the records after that record (including that record). The output shows the package executed successfully without any error.

I tried to reduce the number of records in the file, 3000 records with 2 big record works fine but with 3 records shows the same behavior of skipping records.

Comment: a few screenshots of your configurations might be helpful.  I'd be particularly interested in knowing the details of your connection manager and source component, along with the component writing the data to the SQL DB.  In addition, could you clarify if the "skip" is occurring at the source component, or does everything flow through but never makes it to the target component?

Comment: @AHiggins thanks for the reply! Skip is occurring at the source component. I will try to get the screenshots tomorrow as the project is present at the client system only.